# Laravel 419 session expire after deployment to shared host

Tags: php, laravel, session

I develop multi auth laravel 5.7 application and i works fine in my local env but after deploying it to shared host server and try to login or activate any post request with CSRF token 
the server return 419 session expire please refresh the page.
if i disallow laravel csrf middle-ware it works fine, right now i'm really confused and need any help about this situation or the any information about why laravel will return this error

Comment: Did you check your session configuration?

Comment: can you explain more..

Comment: Apparently your sessions do not persist, you need to review your session configuration. Do you store the sessions in files? Is the directory writeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define application key (`APP_KEY`) before to use laravel application. so run below command for creating new application key

```
php artisan key:generate
```

This will generate a key and put it in your env file.

After that delete your config cache and try again

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the `APP_KEY=` in the .env file

Comment: i use the same env file from my local environment with the app key and change the database configs but still get the same response.

Comment: have you checked your `SESSION_DRIVER=` in the .env file ? is there no error in `storage/logs/laravel.log` file